# Modal that opens an IFRAME (umbraco)

Tags: c#, modal-dialog, umbraco

I'v got a problem when opening a Modal window that loads a JFrame.
The file loaded in the JFrame is a aspx file with a tag of /umbraco/controls/Tree/TreeControl.ascx. The modal loads and any text i put in is loaded but the TreeControl will not load. Iv used this ascx file in other places and it works greate if I load it via a normal page call. If you ar not familiar with umbraco Tree. It's basiclly a jquery tree that loads xml nodes.

Tried to copy code here. But couldnt get formatting to work.

Thx for any help
Best Regards
Marthin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer a problem for me with the new version of Umbraco 4.5